# Calculate the exponentials of big negative value

Tags: r

I would like to know how can I get the exponential of big negative number in R? For example when I try :

```
   > exp(-6400)
   [1] 0
   > exp(-1200)
   [1] 0
   > exp(-2000)
   [1] 0
```

but I need the value of above expression, even if it is so small, how can I get it in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those number are too small. To know the minimum value your computer can handle try:

```
> .Machine$double.xmin
[1] 2.225074e-308
```

Will give you (from `?.Machine`)

> the smallest non-zero normalized floating-point number, a power of the radix, i.e., double.base ^ double.min.exp. Normally 2.225074e-308.

In my case

```
> .Machine$double.base
[1] 2
> .Machine$double.min.exp
[1] -1022
```

Actually I can calculate powers up to

```
> exp(-745)
```

[1] 4.940656e-324

To go around this issue you need [infinite precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

In R you can achieve that using package `Rmpfr` ([PDF vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/Rmpfr-pkg.pdf))

```
library(Rmpfr)
# Calculate exp(-100)
> a <- mpfr(exp(-100), precBits=64)
# exp(-1000)
> a^10

1 'mpfr' number of precision  64   bits 
[1] 5.07595889754945890823e-435
# exp(-6400)

> a^64

1 'mpfr' number of precision  64   bits 
[1] 3.27578823787094497049e-2780
# use an array of powers

> ex <- c(10, 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 1e5)
> a ^ ex

7 'mpfr' numbers of precision  64   bits 
[1]     5.07595889754945890823e-435     2.57653587296115182772e-869
[3]    3.36969414830892462745e-2172    1.13548386531474089222e-4343
[5]   1.88757769782054893243e-21715   3.56294956530952353784e-43430
[7] 1.51693678090513840149e-4342945
```

---

Note that Rmpfr is based on [GNU MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) and requires [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org). Under Linux you will need `gmp`, `gmp-devel`, `mpfr`, and `mpfr-devel` to be installed in your system in order to install these packages, not sure how that works under Windows.

Comment: Thnaks for your reply. If I apply it for a vector of big negative value could i do it or not?

Comment: @rose: sure, I added a few example. Note that I use positive value as `a` is already defined as `exp(-100)`. Also note that if you continue going down at some point you will need to increase the precision. You may want to have a look at the Wikipedia page on [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)