# Large exponent values in R with 'Rmpfr'

Tags: r, floating-point

I am trying to calculate the value of `exp(1000)` or more in R. I looked at the solution provided in [Calculate the exponentials of big negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013309/calculate-the-exponentials-of-big-negative-value/21014173#21014173) and followed it to replicate the code for negative values first, but I have the following output.

```
a <- mpfr(exp(-1000),precBits = 64)
a
1 'mpfr' number of precision  64   bits 
[1] 0
```

I do not understand why my output would be different from the provided solution. I understand this particular solution is for negative values and that I am looking for positive exponents. Regardless, it should work for both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert to extended precision *before* you exponentiate, otherwise R will try to compute `exp(-1000)` with its usual precision and underflow will occur (as you found out).

```r
> a <- exp(mpfr(-1000, precBits = 64))
> a
1 'mpfr' number of precision  64   bits 
[1] 5.07595889754945676548e-435
```